# Pandas minus same row value with next row value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

| Time | Agg | Value | Needed Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:55:00 | 178.0 | 322.0 | 322 |
| 11:00:00 | 354.0 | - | (322-354)-32 |
| 11:05:00 | 354.0 | - | (-32-354)-386 |
| 11:10:00 | 354.0 | - | (-386-next Agg nu) |

How can I calculate the needed value field,

for 1st row it takes the value field as it is,

for 2nd row it takes 2nd row needed value - 3rd row Agg value

for 3rd row, 3rd row needed value -4th row agg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `cumsum` to get cumulative sum of `Agg`, then subtract `Value`:

```
first_val = float(df['Value'].iloc[0])
df['Needed'] = first_val - df['Agg'].iloc[1:].cumsum()
df['Needed'] = df['Needed'].fillna(first_val)
```

Output:

```
        Time    Agg   Value        Needed Value  Needed
0  10:55:00   178.0  322.0                  322   322.0
1  11:00:00   354.0      -         (322-354)-32   -32.0
2  11:05:00   354.0      -        (-32-354)-386  -386.0
3  11:10:00   354.0      -   (-386-next Agg nu)  -740.0
```

Comment: That was such a clean solution, thanks @quang-hoang

Answer (score 1):

For improve performance is used  [**numba**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#using-numba):

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a, b):
    d = np.empty(a.shape)
    d[0] = b[0]
    for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
        d[i] = d[i-1] - a[i]
    return d

df['Needed Value'] = f(df['Agg'].to_numpy(), df['Value'].to_numpy())
print (df)
       Time    Agg  Value  Needed Value
0  10:55:00  178.0  322.0         322.0
1  11:00:00  354.0    NaN         -32.0
2  11:05:00  354.0    NaN        -386.0
3  11:10:00  354.0    NaN        -740.0
```